# Inno Setup: TNewStaticText displays the wrong color

Tags: inno-setup

When I Change Font.Color of a TNewStaticText to any color, the TNewStaticText stays black.
But When I Change Font.Color of a TLabel everything works fine.
But when I use TLabel I get wierd results on windows xp.
Why does TNewStaticText always display the black color?
What stable text in inno setup can I use that won't change color or any other properties on different computers?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The `TNewStaticText` follows its `Font.Color`. What version of Windows are you trying this one? Show us your code.

Comment: Windows 10. But I tried in on another Windows 10 computer and the problem didn't happen, it only happens on my computer.

Comment: It must be some custom theme of your machine. In general, it works.